# Throw exception indicating location of incorrect JSON data without spamming try/catch blocks

Tags: c++, json

I have a complex JSON object with a list of settings, something like this (example is sort of contrived):

```json
{
  "configuration" : {
     "name": "<room name>",
     "players": {"min": 3, "max": 5},
     "options": {
        "rounds": {"prompt": "Enter number of rounds", "default": 10},
        "score_to_win": {"prompt": "Enter score to win", "default": 500}
     }
  }
  // ... lots of other information, can get pretty deeply nested
}
```

I could process it (using nlohmann-json) with something like this:

```cpp
void parse_json(const nlohmann::json &j) {
    nlohmann::json config = j.at("configuration");
    std::string name = config.at("name");
    int minplayers = config.at("players").at("min");
    int maxplayers = config.at("players").at("max");
    for (auto& it : config.at("options").items()) {
        std::string key = it.key();
        std::string prompt = it.value().at("prompt");
        int defval = it.value().at("default");
    }
}
```

But if the JSON is incorrect, it won't give very helpful error messages:

```cpp
try {
    parse_json(nlohmann::json::parse(R"({"configuration" : {
     "name": "cool room name",
     "players": {"min": 4, "max": "6"},
     "options": {
        "rounds": {"prompt": "Enter number of rounds", "default": 10},
        "score_to_win": {"prompt": "Enter score to win", "default": 500}
     }
  }})"));
} catch (std::exception &ex) {
   std::cout << ex.what() << "\n";
}

// [json.exception.type_error.302] type must be number, but is string
```

I could wrap try/catches around each line to say where the exception occurred but that messes up the code. Is there a way to also report where the error is in the JSON without cluttering the code too much?

Comment: Doesn't `parse_error` work?

Comment: @Eljay nah, the JSON is valid, but it might be missing values or have the wrong type. Unless there's a way to use `parse_error` that I don't know about. (maybe I should reword the question title)

Comment: Seems not to be possible, see: https://github.com/nlohmann/json/issues/806

Answer (score 1):

You could keep track of the last accessed path (as a JSON pointer) and report errors on it:

```
void parse_json(const nlohmann::json &j) {
    nlohmann::json::json_pointer last_accessed;
    auto at = [&j, &last_accessed](const nlohmann::json::json_pointer& ptr) {
        last_accessed = ptr;
        return j.at(ptr);
    };
    try {
        auto config_ptr = "/configuration"_json_pointer;
        nlohmann::json config = at(config_ptr);
        std::string name = at(config_ptr / "name");
        ...
    } catch (...) {
        throw last_accessed;
    }
}
```

With a slightly smarter exception type you could report on the underlying nlohmann::json error, but I hope you get the gist of it.

Comment: Thank you, I didn't know about JSON pointers! I tried out your idea and it worked out great. I posted the helper class I wrote in another answer.

Answer (score 1):

Building on @Botje's idea, I made a helper class to update the json pointer. Here it is:

```cpp
#include <string>
#include "nlohmann/json.hpp"
/* 
    LastAccessedHelper(json, json_pointer)
    Construct with a JSON object and a json_pointer to store the access path in
    Supports const or non-const access, change the type alias in the definition accordingly

    "arg" below can be a json_pointer, string, or size_t

    at(arg) - return json at a given position
    at() - access json at root -- effectively "convert" helper to json object
    enter(arg) - move last_accessed to a new location and return child helper based at new location
    exit() - tell child helper to move last_accessed back to the previous location
*/

// helper function to count the number of levels in a pointer, no native way of doing it
int json_ptr_size(const nlohmann::json::json_pointer &_ptr) {
    // make a copy and pop_back() until the root :(
    nlohmann::json::json_pointer ptr(_ptr);
    int size = 0;
    while (!ptr.empty()) {
        ptr.pop_back();
        size++;
    }
    return size;
}

struct LastAccessedHelper {
    using json = const nlohmann::json;      // set to be const or non-const based on your use case
    using json_pointer = nlohmann::json::json_pointer;

    json &j;
    json_pointer &last_accessed;
    int at_level;
    int exit_level;

    LastAccessedHelper(json &j, json_pointer &last_accessed)
        : j{j}, last_accessed{last_accessed}, at_level{0}, exit_level{0}
    {}
    LastAccessedHelper(json &j, json_pointer &last_accessed, int exit_level)
        : j{j}, last_accessed{last_accessed}, at_level{0}, exit_level{exit_level}
    {}
    
    /* at() - return json at a given position */
    json& at(const json_pointer& ptr) {
        reset();
        at_level = json_ptr_size(ptr);
        last_accessed /= ptr;
        return j.at(ptr);
    }
    json& at(const std::string &s) {
        return at(json_pointer() / s);
    }
    json& at(size_t t) {
        return at(json_pointer() / t);
    }

    /* at() no arguments - "convert" LastAccessedHelper to a json object */
    json& at() {
        return at(json_pointer());
    }

    /* enter() - move last_accessed to a new location and return child helper based at new location */
    LastAccessedHelper enter(const json_pointer& ptr) {
        reset();
        last_accessed /= ptr;
        return LastAccessedHelper(j.at(ptr), last_accessed, json_ptr_size(ptr));
    }
    LastAccessedHelper enter(const std::string &s) {
        return enter(json_pointer() / s);
    }
    LastAccessedHelper enter(size_t t) {
        return enter(json_pointer() / t);
    }

    /* exit() - tell child helper to move last_accessed back to the previous location */
    void exit() {
        reset();
        unwind(exit_level);
        exit_level = 0;
    }

    /* helpers */
    void unwind(int levels) {
        for (int i=0; i<levels; i++) {
            last_accessed.pop_back();
        }
    }
    void reset() {
        unwind(at_level);
        at_level = 0;
    }
};
```

The main changes to @Botje's solution are

- in-place modification of the path using concatenations and pop_back()
- a "checkpoint" feature `enter()`/`exit()` which creates helpers at new locations to reduce the levels of indirection.

With it, the sample code looks like this:

```cpp
void parse_json(const nlohmann::json &j) {
    nlohmann::json::json_pointer last_accessed;
    LastAccessedHelper acc{j, last_accessed};
    try {
        auto config = acc.enter("configuration");
        std::string name = config.at("name");
        int maxplayers = config.at("/players/max"_json_pointer);
        int minplayers = config.at("/players/min"_json_pointer);
        auto options = config.enter("options");
        for (auto& [key,val] : options.at().items()) {
            nlohmann::json::json_pointer key_ptr;
            key_ptr /= key;
            std::string prompt = options.at(key_ptr / "prompt");
            int defval = options.at(key_ptr / "default");
        }
        options.exit();
        config.exit();
    } catch (std::exception &ex) {
        throw std::runtime_error("Exception at " + last_accessed.to_string() + ": " + ex.what());
    }
}
```

You can use it in subfunctions and recursively too:

```cpp
void parse_tree(const nlohmann::json &j, nlohmann::json::json_pointer &last_accessed) {
    LastAccessedHelper acc{j, last_accessed};
    int value = acc.at("value");
    for (auto& [key,val] : acc.at("children").items()) {
        last_accessed /= key;
        parse_tree(val, last_accessed);
        last_accessed.pop_back();
    }
}

void parse_json(const nlohmann::json &j) {
    nlohmann::json::json_pointer last_accessed;
    LastAccessedHelper acc{j, last_accessed};
    try {
        parse_tree(acc.at("tree"), last_accessed);
    } catch (std::exception &ex) {
        throw std::runtime_error("Exception at " + last_accessed.to_string() + ": " + ex.what());
    }
}

/* Will parse something like
{"tree": {
    "value" : -50,
    "children": [
        {"value": -30, "children": []},
        {"value": 20, "children": [{"value": 10, "children": []}]}
    ]
}}
*/
```

It's not perfect but it works for my use case and is relatively small; I figure it'll be useful for people with the same problem. Some improvement points I can see are:

- RAII the `enter()`/`exit()`? Using `std::uncaught_exceptions()` possibly, if it's worth it
- Better support for iteration, either add a helper function or make it cheaper to instantiate
- Improve the `json_ptr_size()` function

Feel free to suggest/make improvements if you see them :)